# Sitecore gender personalization

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, personalization

I added personalization rule in my Sitecore site - "Where the gender of the current contact is Male", but I can't figure out how to set "Visitors settings" to test it.

I'll be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you have the gender coming from? Is that extended user profile? Also what is your Sitecore version?

Comment: I added this condition using Device Editor -> Controls -> Personalization, then I selected that gender condition from the conditions list. My current Sitecore version is 8. Tnaks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only Gender condition I found in default Sitecore 8 installation is the one coming from Social module (that is now built-in) located at `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Macros/Social/Gender` in Sitecore tree. Looking up its code I see the following code:

```
protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
{
  if (!AnalyticsSettings.Enabled || Tracker.Current == null || Tracker.Current.Contact == null)
    return false;
  return string.Equals(this.GenderValue, ((IGenderConditionManager) ResolutionExtensions.Get<IGenderConditionManager>((IResolutionRoot) ExecutingContext.Current.IoC, new IParameter[0])).GetGender(GuidExtensions.GetIdentifier(Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId)).ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

From the code above we can see that to make Gender condition work, you should have analytics and tracking up and running. So if you have that enabled - ensure all settings are correct and it works indeed.

User membership provider does not have gender settings by itself; so the rule  condition above can take it only from tracking.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Now I get this general idea about Sitecore conditions, so, I realize that actually I would have to create my custom one to work independently of "Social" module. Thank you again for your response and time!

Comment: You are welcome! It is not difficult to create your own condition at all, for your case is more important where exactly you would take user's gender from. Very likely that hat would be extended membership profiles, but that of course depends on your implementation